# How to give custom text colour for a single menu item in a NavigationView?

Tags: android, material-design, navigationview

Hi I am using android **NavigationView**. I want to give seperate text colour for some items in the NavigationView, not for all items. OR I want to change the text colour for a single item dynamically when I select an item in the NavigationView(**Only for certain items**). How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes You can do it **I have also done it**.

First fetch the MenuItem to which you want to change the color

```
 Menu m = navView.getMenu();
 MenuItem menuItem = m.findItem(your_menu_id);
```

then apply spannable with your color

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.your_color), 0, s.length(), 0);
menuItem.setTitle(s);
```

thats it..

**Now Below code is for your 2nd solution changing text color dynamically on Menu click..**

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            SpannableString s = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
            s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0);
            menuItem.setTitle(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Very sneaky! Seems like a complete oversight seeing as you can grab the icon drawable for a single menu item. Thanks!

Comment: This is gold! I had too search way too long for this, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. I have searched (as I am sure you have) to try to find an example of how to accomplish this, and cannot find one.

I would really suggest creating a custom view to do what you are trying to do (which is not very well detailed in your question, so it is a bit hard to suggest an alternative). Or, if you really want to use something provided by the SDK maybe you can use the `OptionsMenu` (which should allow for customization of individual menu items).

EDIT: It turns out it is possible to do this without a custom view. See the accepted answer from moinkhan for details.

Comment: Hi, it is possible. see the answer! :)

Comment: Thanks! I updated my response for anyone who stumbles upon this thread.